# Streaming video from one server thru another

Tags: php, video, curl

I need a help with my script, I spend ages working out what is wrong with it, but I can't find anything.

Basically on my first server I contain video files, on my second server I stream those files. To get the files from the first server you have to use IP from the server two (Basically I allow just my servers to connect with the first server)

So to get those files I use cURL function because all video will pass server two.

I did this :

```
$url = "111.111.111.111/example.flv";

                                    $ch = curl_init();
                                    $timeout = 0;
                                    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                                    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

                                    $video = curl_exec($ch);
                                    curl_close($ch);
                                    // output to browser
                                    header("Content-type: video/x-flv");

                                   echo ' <a href="'.$video.'" style="display:block;width:920px;height:600px" id="player"> 
    </a> 
    <script>
        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
    </script>';
```

So what I did is :
1. I have a link to the video in $url
2. I open new connection using cURL
3. I take data from the link.
4. Then I keep this video in $video
5. And I try to open it.

But but it doesn't work... When I open this website is show me this :

```
FLV���  �����ÖY��������
onMetaData����metadatacreator�3Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.8�hasKeyframes�hasVideo�hasAudio�hasMetadata�canSeekToEnd�duration�@Ļj◊
=p§�datasize�AĽ≥i����   videosize�A∂ąęZ���� framerate�@9�70Ō'�
videodatarate�@|<GłÕŰĢ�videocodecid�@�������width�@Ą�������height�@v@������ audiosize�AĒ8»,����
audiodatarate�@Xsöł¶@ű�audiocodecid�@$�������audiosamplerate�@�������audiosamplesize�?ū�������stereo�filesize�AĽ≥Óv����
lasttimestamp�@Ļj◊
=p§�lastkeyframetimestamp�@Ļj◊
=p§�lastkeyframelocation�AĽ≥Ób����  keyframes�
filepositions
```

So I get data in string...

Do you know what I have to do, to stream this file ??

Comment: Please post the full code that outputs the FLV.

Comment: That's all... the last line it's just a code for a webplayer "echo ' <a href="'.$video.'" style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px" id="player"> 
        </a> 
        <script>
            flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
        </script>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't output both the HTML and the FLV data at the same time. I'd recommend creating a separate PHP file with the following code:

```
$url = "111.111.111.111/example.flv";

header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then you can put your player code anywhere else, like:

```
<a href="/path/to/first/file.php" style="display:block;width:920px;height:600px" id="player">
```

Comment: Thanks you, now it's working, but I've got another problem... When I playing the video, it's playing from the beginning and you can't change the time on the timeline, you can't start form 3:10 you have to watch it from the beginning. Have you got any idea what I have to do to enable this function in the player ?? For example to start watch the video from the middle not from the beginning ??

Comment: Might be related to the player. Does it work if you point the player to a "real" FLV rather than a PHP script that reads one?

Comment: If I copy the video form server one to server two, yes it does work like I want. Is there is any way to output the video from server one in flv format ? i add "header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=video.flv");" to my script but it just change the format then I try to go to the script page.

Comment: Do you think that .htaccess rule can help ? for example "RewriteRule ^(.*).flv$ show.php?video=$1 [L]" Or it's more complicated and I have to use some function in php that will get an information about the video for example how logn it is etc. ?

Comment: I think you may need to update your cURL code to pass on the special headers sent by the browser when trying to seek to a specific time in the player. That's a somewhat different topic so you should probably post a separate question for that.